# Can we just consider thermionic emission as a kind of thermoelectricity?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermoelectricity

I read some thermionic applications, specially the magnetron one with a cathode and an anode. Technically, it seems that the emission of electrons will go towards the anode (cold temperature) whenever the cathode is heated at very high temperature (i.e existence of high thermal gradient). So, by acknowledging those facts, i assume that the medium (open air in our example) can exhibit very high seebeck effect at high temperature even though it's known to be electrically an insulator.

What are your toughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to call things what you wish. Just make sure you define your terms clearly in your publications, or people will be mighty confused.

Comment: Hi Gilbert, Thanks for your answer ! The main reason of my publication is that during my research on thermionic application, i did not see people linking this subject to thermoelectricity. However, may be i am wrong by assuming thermionic is simply seebeck effect?